# ¿No puedo acceder a mi aplicación web con solo ingresar mi nombre de dominio?

Tags: java, web, dominio

¿Me podrían ayudar con un problema que me surgió? Es el siguiente: Tengo una aplicación java que acceso con la siguiente dirección url `http://midominio:8080/contexto/pagina.jsp`.

¿Hay alguna forma de eliminar la ruta dentro de la URL? Es decir, la parte de `/contexto/pagina.jsp` para acceder solo con escribir `midominio`?

Comment: Sí, el contexto debe ser el contexto raíz, y pagina.jsp debe configurarse como la pagina default. En tomcat el contexto raiz es Root si no me equivoco y en el web.xml tenes que agregar pagina.jsp en `<welcome-file-list><welcome-file>pagina.jsp</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>`.

Comment: Gracias ya salio.